# How to run MapReduce jobs without HDFS?

Tags: mount, hadoop

So I'm using Hadoop with 8 nodes, all of them are configured as workers (I'm not interested in the namenode/datanodes architecture, I just need them as compute nodes that run on yarn without HDFS as I'm using another file system for data storage). I added the following configuration in core-site.xml:

```
<property>
        <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
        <value>viewfs:///</value>
</property>
<property>
        <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
        <value>/tmp/</value>
</property>
<property>
        <name>fs.AbstractFileSystem.file.impl</name>
        <value>org.apache.hadoop.fs.local.LocalFs</value>
</property>
<property>
        <name>fs.viewfs.mounttable.default.link./tmp</name>
        <value>file:/tmp/hadoop_fuse/hadoop/tmp</value>
</property>
<property>
        <name>fs.viewfs.mounttable.default.link./user</name>
        <value>file:/tmp/hadoop_fuse/hadoop/user</value>
</property>

</configuration>
```

When I run TestDFSIO I get the error:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: File/Directory does not exist:
>   /benchmarks

How do I run this job and make it store data at the mount point /tmp/hadoop_fuse/?